# Get Specific Index of Specific item from <select> to evaluate later

Tags: javascript

Okay to start of this is my main script that does the calculation for my specific problem, I don't understand why it doesn't output the correct result which is "Success" on the specified ID that I put it on. Is it something wrong with the index evaluations or I didn't properly get the index from my  form.

```
function calculatePrice(){
  var startLeague;
  var targetLeague;

  var startDiv;
  var targetDiv;

  var temp = document.getElementById("startLeague");

  startLeague = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
  startLeague = temp.indexOf(startLeague);

  temp = document.getElementById("targetLeague");

  targetLeague = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
  targetLeague = temp.indexOf(targetLeague);

  temp = document.getElementById("startDiv");

  startDiv = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
  startDiv = startDiv.indexOf(startDiv);

  temp = document.getElementById("targetDiv");

  targetDiv = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
  targetDiv = temp.indexOf(targetDiv);

  if(startLeague >= targetLeague){
    document.getElementById("price-box").innerHTML = "Cannot Calculate";

    //Ignore this line
    setTimeout(initPrice, 5000);
  }else{
    if(startDiv >= targetDiv){
      document.getElementById("price-box").innerHTML = "Cannot Calculate";

      //Ignore this line
      setTimeout(initPrice, 5000);
    }else{
      document.getElementById("price-box").innerHTML = "Success";
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I have for my HTML code and represents the values to be taken from the HTML itself via DOM.

```
  <select id="startLeague">
    <option value="Someval">0</option>
    <option value="Someval1">1</option>
    <option value="Someval2">2</option>
    <option value="Someval3">3</option>
    <option value="Someval4">4</option>
  </select>

  <select id="targetLeague">
    <option value="Someval">0</option>
    <option value="Someval1">1</option>
    <option value="Someval2">2</option>
    <option value="Someval3">3</option>
    <option value="Someval4">4</option>
  </select>
```

And so on...

This is my output paragraph that is used to check the value, so far when I click the button it doesn't do anything and remains blank, what is the problem?

```
<p id="price-box" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"></p>
```

Clicking on the button as mentioned above doesn't do anything whereas it should be working.

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Calculate</button>
```

As a final note, yes I have included the following line on the HTML head tag

```
<script src="price.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html?

Comment: There you, the rest of the <select> attributes are the same :)

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What is the outcome you'd expect and what you actually receive?

Comment: The problem is that it never reached the "Success" point and the value is empty in the HTML

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You are accessing the value of the option which will return 'Someval1' for example. Is that what you want?

Comment: When the conditions are satisfied it was to output the message "Success" on the item that has "price-box" as the id, which doesn't happen and I don't know why.

Comment: You are showing way to less code. How do you trigger the price-calculation? Please show us the context of your code. We don't know where you access the dom in your code with only that snippet

Comment: How about now? Is that okay?

Comment: `if(startLeague > targetLeague || startLeague == targetLeague)` – you’re aware the `>=` operator exists, right …?

Comment: Yes but why are you using temp.indexOf? You already have the value?

Comment: I wanna compare the indexes instead, makes it much easier to use that instead of the actual values @Christian